# Second order ODE for constant external force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, spring, oscillators

Given a general ODE for damped spring with constant external due to gravity $$my'' + \gamma y' + k y = -mg$$ where $m, \gamma, k, g$ are positive. I have to show that given an initial condition, the solution $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} y(t) = -\frac{mg}{k}$. To solve the ODE wouldnt the particular solution just be $y(t) = -\frac{mg}{k}$? We dont need to worry about the transient since its gonna be zero as $t \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Your task is probably to show that the transient is going to be zero for $t\rightarrow\infty$ instead of just... knowing that it is. Or, depending on how nit-picky you want to be, that everything else is transient in the first place.

Comment: @noah yeah the general solution is gonna be $y(t) = c_1e^{r_1t} + c_2e^{r_2t} - \frac{mg}{k}$, where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are given by the characteristic equation to the homogenous equation. Then the limit as t approaches infinity goes to $-mg/k$

Answer (score 3):

To render that DE homogeneous, here's a little trick:
$$my'' + \gamma y' + k y = -mg$$
$$my'' + \gamma y' + k y +mg=0$$
Make a substitution:
$$z=ky+mg$$
Take the derivatives:
$$z'=ky'\Rightarrow\gamma y'=\frac{\gamma}{k}z'$$
$$z''=k y''\Rightarrow my''=\frac{m}{k}z''$$
Insert into the DE:
$$\frac{m}{k}z''+\frac{\gamma}{k}z'+z=0$$
Solve and back-substitute.

This trick works for all linear, non-homogeneous DEs, as long as the RHS is a **constant** (and not a function).

Comment: this is very helpful. Would this also work in the case when there is no damping? i.e. $my'' + ky = -mg$?

Comment: @UnKnoWnZ Yes, I've done that one on the pages of this here site. It works for all linear DEs, as long as the 'heterogeneity' is a **constant**.